# update object options on option form

Tags: options

I have an object on an option called 'option_voc'.
Now I would like to update only one field of this object through form i created on menu page i created (The plugin's settings page).
I do not find the way to make this happen?

Here is my code:

```
// Register the option
function seexperts_init() {
    register_setting('option_group', 'option_voc');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'seexperts_init');

function se_settings_page() {
    ?> 
    <div id="wrap">
    <?php screen_icon(); ?>
        <h2>Test Title</h2>
        <form action="options.php" method="post" id="se-experts-settings-form">
    <?php settings_fields('option_group'); $the_valu_of_close_bar_title = get_option('option_voc');?>
            <h3>
                <label for="option_voc">close_bar_title</label>
                <input type="text" id="option_voc" name="option_voc" value="<?php echo $the_valu_of_close_bar_title['close_bar_title'];?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Settings"/>
            </h3>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```